# How to have two search bar on action bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-actionbar, appbar

What is the correct way to achieve something like image below?

[image]

I add column and row in appBar, but get this

[image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
      child: AppBar(
          title: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.access_alarm), Text("idwidjow")]),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.access_alarm), Text("idwidjow")],
          )
        ],
      )),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about to try something like this... You will have to finish the design though

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
    child: AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                width: 50,
              ),
              Icon(Icons.person),
              Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                ),
              ))),
              Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 50),
              Icon(Icons.person),
              Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
              Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Output

[image]